# MongoDB as a prerequisite in Advanced Installer

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

I want to silently install MongoDB as a prerequisite. The problem is to pass the command line arguments. 
The usual command( without AI ) is:

```
msiexec.exe /q /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl 3.6.4-signed.msi INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6.4\" ADDLOCAL="all" SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0"
```

My question is how and where to pass these arguments "INSTALLLOCATION, ADDLOCAL, SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS" in Advanced installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your prerequisite then go to *Setup Files* tab. There set all 3 fields from "Install Command Lines" to:

> /qn ADDLOCAL="all" SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0"

Comment: Thank you! Working fine by setting command lines to:
/qn ADDLOCAL="all" SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0"